# Converting Easy Language Code to C# Code Caused Some Issues

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a math function written in easy language code to C# but I'm having a very simple but very frustrating error in my code where the values keep going down the more values I run the calculation with. I have attached screenshots of the code and what I'm getting returned. I'm sure it is just a typo in my code but I can't find it. Let me know if you need to see anything else

Here is my code:

```
public static (List<double>, List<double>) CalculateEhlersRoofingFilter(List<double> valuesList, int days)
    {
        List<double> highPassList = new List<double>();
        List<double> roofingFilterList = new List<double>();

        int lowerPeriod = days;
        int upperPeriod = Utils.MinOrMax((int)Math.Ceiling(lowerPeriod / 0.2083));

        double alphaArg = Utils.ToRadians((0.707 * 360) / upperPeriod);
        double alphaCos = Math.Cos(alphaArg);
        double alpha1;
        if (alphaCos != 0)
        {
            alpha1 = (alphaCos + Math.Sin(alphaArg) - 1) / alphaCos;
        }
        else
        {
            alpha1 = 0;
        }

        double a1 = Math.Exp((-1.414 * 3.14159) / lowerPeriod);
        double b1 = 2 * a1 * Math.Cos(Utils.ToRadians((1.414 * 180) / lowerPeriod));
        double c2 = b1;
        double c3 = (-1 * a1) * a1;
        double c1 = 1 - c2 - c3;

            for (int i = 0; i < valuesList.Count; i++)
            {
                double currentValue = valuesList.ElementAt(i);

                double prevValue1, prevValue2, prevFilter1, prevFilter2, prevHp1, prevHp2;
                if (i >= 1)
                {
                    prevValue1 = valuesList.ElementAt(i - 1);
                    prevFilter1 = roofingFilterList.ElementAt(i - 1);
                    prevHp1 = highPassList.ElementAt(i - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    prevValue1 = currentValue;
                    prevFilter1 = currentValue;
                    prevHp1 = currentValue;
                }
                if (i >= 2)
                {
                    prevFilter2 = roofingFilterList.ElementAt(i - 2);
                    prevValue2 = valuesList.ElementAt(i - 2);
                    prevHp2 = highPassList.ElementAt(i - 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    prevFilter2 = currentValue;
                    prevValue2 = currentValue;
                    prevHp2 = currentValue;
                }

                double highPass = (Utils.Power((1 - alpha1) / 2, 2) * (currentValue - (2 * prevValue1) + prevValue2)) + (2 * (1 - alpha1) * prevHp1) - 
                    (Utils.Power(1 - alpha1, 2) * prevHp2);
                highPassList.Add(highPass);

                double roofingFilter = (c1 * ((highPass + prevHp1) / 2)) + (c2 * prevFilter1) + (c3 * prevFilter2);
                roofingFilterList.Add(roofingFilter);
            }

        return (highPassList, roofingFilterList);
    }
```

What I'm trying to implement in my code:
[image]

What the formula returns:
[image]

The input values I'm using:
[image]

Comment: You need to debug your code and see if it works as per the logic.

Comment: I suggest you write the c# code to match as closely as possible the original-- same variable names, same order of operations, even same code formatting if possible. That way you can step through both code bases and inspect variables as you go, making sure they match exactly. Once you have it working to spec, *then* you can clean up the code to make it more idomatic for c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, it might be challenging to find the problem without knowing exactly what you are looking for.  However, I would recommend changing "lowerPeriod" and "upperPeriod" to double for consistency in the calculations (let the value be assigned from the int on the right), and put a 'D' after each constant to force them to be treated as a double instead of potential an int or a float, etc...  Using "2D" is "2 as a double" as opposed to "2", which is an 'int' and you have to worry about interactions of different numeric types and hope the rules work out the way that you expect.